# Where do webpack:// files live, and how are they generated?

Tags: css, webpack, react-scripts

I am very much a novice regarding the Node ecosystem, and my intention is to update my team's React/Typescript app from react-scripts 4.x to 5.x.  I'm seeing an error which I don't understand (actually a warning, but CircleCI is failing b/c it's on strict mode) when I execute `npx react-app-rewired build --aot --no-watch --no-progress`:

```
static/css/main.109f02ad.css from Css Minimizer plugin
postcss-svgo:: Invalid character in tag name

> 1 | <svg+xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"+width="1"+height="1"+viewBox="0+0+1+1"><…
    |     ^

 webpack://./src/app/styles/genome-extraction-datatable.css:1:0
```

My app does have a `styles/genome-extraction-datatable.css` but the text `svg` and `xmlns` do not appear in it.  So this `webpack://` file must be generated ... but how?

Also, removing the source CSS file does not resolve the error.  It complains about a different CSS file in that case.

Is this enough information to help me get started?  Please let me know what additional information would be useful here.  I know nothing about webpack.